# How does one NOT draw a connecting line with SciDraw's DataLine options? I only wish to plot the points

Tags: scidraw

For instance, my SciDraw code I'm using that draws a dashed line. I would like to find out how to not draw the LineDashing. I've tried setting the point size to 0 and to say False. I cannot find the options for DataLine in the SciDraw User's guide.

```
Data = {{4.35, 2.76, 0.191, 0.240}, {3.96, 2.70, 0., 0.27}, {1.966, 
   0.659, 0.00, 0.0}, {0.770, 0.165, 0.057, 0.009}, {0.468, 0, 0, 
   0.002}, {0.173, 0, 0, 0.022}}

DefineStyle["LA",
 {
  FigurePanel -> {
    XPlotRange -> {0, 5},
    XExtendRange -> 0.05,
    XFrameLabel -> Row[{"Deconvoluted THz pulse", " (V)"}],
    XFrameLabelPosition -> 0.5,
    YPlotRange -> {-0.010, 5},
    YFrameLabel -> Row[{"Deconvoluted LA phonon pulse", " (V)"}],
    YFrameLabelPosition -> 0.5
    }
  }
 ]

DefineStyle[
  "DataPlot", {DataLine -> {LineDashing -> 4}, 
   DataSymbol -> {SymbolShape -> "Square", FillColor -> Red, 
     SymbolSize -> 6}}];
DefineStyle[
  "DataMarker", {FigCircle -> {Radius -> Absolute[8], 
     FillColor -> Moccasin, Layer -> 0}}];
Figure[
 {
  FigurePanel[
   {
    DataPlot[Data, YErrorColumn -> 3, XErrorColumn -> 4, 
     Style -> "DataPlot"];
    FigGraphics[
     Plot[0.137 (x - 0.006)^2, {x, 0, 4.5}, PlotStyle -> Firebrick]];
    
    
    
    }
   ]
  },
 Style -> "LA"
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid a connecting line  (thanks to Mark Caprio for explanation .. creator of SciDraw)

````
DataLine -> {Show -> False}

```
````